# Meteor: apply function after rendering things from mongodb

Tags: mongodb, meteor, sage

I am using sage cell to convert html to math stuff

```
Template.home.rendered = function(){
  \\ apply sagecell and mathjax
}
```

However, the content that are rendered comes from mongo, so it's sometimes loaded after sage cell is applied to it. I can do something like this

```
Template.home.rendered = function(){
  Deps.autorun(function(){
    if (Content.findOne({_id: ...})){
      \\ apply sagecell and mathjax
    }
  });
}
```

It's better but still doesn't work all the time. Is there other things I can use to detect the content is completely rendered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The script

```
<script type='text/javascript' src="http://sagecell.sagemath.org/static/embedded_sagecell.js"></script>
```

that is supposed to be in the head needs to be removed and instead be loaded after the content is completely loaded like so:

```
Template.content.rendered = function(){
  // sage
  Deps.autorun(function(){
    if (Session.get('contentChanged')){
      // loading this script causes mathjax to run
      $.getScript("http://sagecell.sagemath.org/static/embedded_sagecell.js", function(d, textStatus){
        if (textStatus=='success'){
          // this converts <div class='compute'> to a sage cell
          sagecell.makeSagecell({
            inputLocation: 'div.compute',
            evalButtonText: 'Evaluate',
            hide: ['editorToggle']
          });
        }
      })
    }
  })
```

and if I go from 1 content template to another content template, it seems that nothing is rerendered and so the mathjax was not applied. The only fix I can think is to force a page reload:

```
Template.content.events({
'click a': function(evt){
  evt.preventDefault();
  location.href = evt.currentTarget.href;
}
})
```

which makes the site much slower, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

Edited with new response:

```
<template name='pendingAnswer'>
    The answer to your question, coming back whenever, is:
    {{>answer}}
</template>

<template name='answer'>
    {{fromSage}}
</template>     

Template.answer.helpers({ 
    fromSage: function () {  
        Session.get('fromSage');
    }
});

Invoked whenever - from a button, from navigating to the page, on blur...        
function GetAnswerFromSage(data) {
        callHTTP(website,data, callbackFromSage)
}        

function callbackFromSage(err, data) {
        if (err) then log(err);
        Session.set('fromSage', data);
        }
```

Earlier: try transform upon retrieval of mongo:
[From Meteor Doc](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_collection)

```
// An Animal class that takes a document in its constructor
Animal = function (doc) {
  _.extend(this, doc);
};
_.extend(Animal.prototype, {
  makeNoise: function () {
    console.log(this.sound);
  }
});

// Define a Collection that uses Animal as its document
Animals = new Meteor.Collection("Animals", {
  transform: function (doc) { return new Animal(doc); }
});

// Create an Animal and call its makeNoise method
Animals.insert({name: "raptor", sound: "roar"});
Animals.findOne({name: "raptor"}).makeNoise(); // prints "roar"
```

Comment: Are you suggesting that I should add makeNoise() to a Content document? But then that would be the same as checking whether findOne has returned something non-null, no?

Comment: As each document comes from mongo, your constructor will be called.  This is when I recommend you perform your conversions (unless you want something to be lazy).  You are in total control of when it changes, and reactivity makes sure it is promptly rendered.  To organize your code, it may make sense to add that to one or more makeNoise methods.  This is not adding it to the document collection.  You would need to call mongo updates to perform that.  Animal is just your organizational representation, a smart model.

Comment: The problem is that I have no control over when the conversion is done. I am using an external api offered by http://sagecell.sagemath.org/

Comment: Using the session sounds ok then.  As soon as you save, any dependent html will update.  Not until.  So always when you need it to.

In your question, you are doing something when the template is rendered.  Instead, do something when you have your data complete.

Comment: Yes, that's what I should do. When I do that, I found out what the bug: it turns out the script that defines sagecell (not the one that runs sagecell) must be run after the text is loaded. See details at the answer I post

Comment: Consider downloading and adding that script to your project.  You can edit it to only start on your command.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/18541710/953759

Comment: The problem is that there are other dependencies in that script that call other files, like MathJax, using relative path, so it will take some nontrivial work to do what you said, I think. Anyway, I am okay with it being slow at this point. Thanks.